# Take input and apply to another url

Tags: java, php, html

Hey I want to develop a website which basically allows customers to visit my site and add orders to there cart. On check when user enters payment credentials i basically want to submit a process to alibabas webpage to the direct order linked to on my webpage, and place an order through the site using there shipping/billing and payment info. That way when they complete checkout on my homepage alibab will have sent me an email saying i have order and item for (user inputfields from my webpage from) and all the other info alibaba sends on there checkout. Basically all orders will go through my account, but there will be different shipping and payment methods..

If something like this is possible could someone possible point me in the right direction to creating something like this?

I don't mind creating a java web applet for this e-commerce site.

Comment: Your question is too broad to really give a meaningful answer. If you are struggling with a specific issue with your code or design then we are more likely to be able to help.

Comment: I didn't get please explain with some more content?

Comment: If you want to redirect them to a site you can use header() in PHP

Comment: Why should all orders go through your account? Sounds like you are trying to insert yourself into the middle of a transaction, that could easily do without your involvement in the first place. What’s the purpose, trying to skim off some commission of the top or benefit from mass discounts, on the back of your unsuspecting “customers” …?